# SQL - Rails query between opening and closing time of store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using postgresql as my database.
Currently i have timing model , which contains `open_at` and `close_at` fields. both fields data type is time .

```
2.4.2 :077 > Time.current
 => Tue, 20 Mar 2018 06:46:28 UTC +00:00 

=> #<Timing id: 3, day: "Tuesday", open_at: "2000-01-01 04:00:00", close_at: "2000-01-01 01:00:00", warehouse_id: 9, created_at: "2018-03-19 10:45:36", updated_at: "2018-03-20 06:34:16">
```

Above timing record's opening time is 4 am and closing time is 1 am . current time is 6:46. so when i do below query

```
2.4.2 :079 > Timing.where("open_at < ? and close_at > ?", Time.current, Time.current)
  Timing Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "timings".* FROM "timings" WHERE (open_at < '2018-03-20 06:48:09.004429' and close_at > '2018-03-20 06:48:09.004496') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

it should come as result, but result is empty but when i change closing time to 11 pm means 23:00:00. and run below query

```
Timing.where("open_at < ? and close_at > ?", Time.current, Time.current)
  Timing Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "timings".* FROM "timings" WHERE (open_at < '2018-03-20 06:49:12.307156' and close_at > '2018-03-20 06:49:12.307205') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Timing id: 3, day: "Tuesday", open_at: "2000-01-01 04:00:00", close_at: "2000-01-01 23:59:00", warehouse_id: 9, created_at: "2018-03-19 10:45:36", updated_at: "2018-03-20 06:49:07">]>
```

the result comes. can anybody explain what is issue with time ? or how should i query if i want to get correct records

**

**Update - add timings table in schema.rb**

**

schema.rb

```
  create_table "timings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "day"
    t.time "open_at"
    t.time "close_at"
    t.bigint "warehouse_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["warehouse_id"], name: "index_timings_on_warehouse_id"
  end
```

Comment: Maybe the problem  is in the time format. If I'm not mistaken DB always store time in 24h forma and so your closing time is less than open time (in first case).

Comment: @kunashir  Yes , you are right. but how to over come this issue ?

Comment: use `time` format instead of `datetime` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: @meta currently data type of fields is time. and also checking current time only. so may be thats not issue

Comment: no, this is clearly a `datetime` (`timestamp` in PQ terminology) format: "2000-01-01 04:00:00", what you need is `time` which looks like this "04:00:00"

Comment: @meta , this is "2000-01-01" by default taken by pg in time field, but it will never compare date

Comment: Please share your schema.rb file. It looks like your database column is actually a datetime and you think it’s only time.  We’ll be able to help more effectively if you provide your Timing tables schema.

Comment: @danielricecodes Updated my question. please take look it

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is time format, you can use next:

```
Time.now.strftime("%I:%M %p") #=> It returns current time in AM/PM format
Time.strptime( '1:00 PM', '%I:%M %p') #=> return time in 24 hours format
=> 2018-03-20 13:00:00 +0300
```

And use it for making request to DB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but currently it is also taking 24 hours format. because i can store time in 24 hours format and `Time.current` also returning 24 hours format . i need query how it will work

Comment: `close_at: "2000-01-01 01:00:00"` - I think it's incorrect (it's 1 hour of night). I've suggested you get a time from frontend in AM/PM format if yes you need to convert it manual to 24h format.

Comment: yes ,  `close_at: "2000-01-01 01:00:00"`is 1 hour of night. in my case, store opening time is 8 AM and closing time is 1 AM. are you getting my point ? if i store close at 1 PM than i store close time as `close_at: "2000-01-01 13:00:00"`

Comment: postgres is smart enough  to understand AM/PM format also. like  `Timing.where('open_at::time > ? AND  close_at::time < ?', '07:00:00 AM', '01:00:00 AM')` is also correct but it will not return any data

Comment: Oh.. I see. Interesting case.